# EXCEL VLOOKUP - Extracting multiple columns from one formula

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to use a VLOOKUP array formula to extract and display multiple columns using one formula.

Excel Formula:

=VLOOKUP(A15,A1:G9,{3,4,5},FALSE)

```
  1                      2             3          4        5          6
Transaction ID      Payment Date    Product    Quantity   Cost       Sales 
MVLN195             1/3/2014        Trash Can   1         $14.00     $14.00 
XFYR246             1/4/2014        Lawnmower   1         $599.00    $599.00    
DWDF167             1/4/2014        Diapers     1         $29.00     $29.00 
YNBM339             1/5/2014        Sweater     3         $59.00     $177.00    
WTKQ758             1/7/2014        Bike        1         $599.00    $599.00
SFKS527             1/7/2014        Radio       1         $25.00     $25.00 
OGWT288             1/8/2014        Bike        1         $599.00    $599.00    
TCQN516             1/9/2014        Calender    5         $3.00      $15.00

  1        2         3         4        
ID       Product   Quantity   Cost
OGWT288  Bike      #N/A       #N/A
```

I've tried using the array vlookup formula, but only column 3 comes up. I've tried to press ctrl shift enter as well but still only data from column is pulled not for the other two.

If anyone could be of any assistance would be very helpful.

Thank You

Comment: thank you for both your comments. First time using VlOOKUP after a long time, didn't realise you had to click and drag or select the cells you want to populate, didn't state that in the tuturials. Thought the array would auto populate the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your formula is correct.

Put it in the first column, in your scenario it's A16.

And then select that cell and drag it upto the next 3 cells.

Move your mouse cursor to the top formula bar and click over, and press ctrl+shift+enter

It should work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the first cell and drag over:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$15,$A$1:$G$9,COLUMN(C:C),FALSE)
```

[image]

If you really want to array enter then you can use your formula:

1. Select B15:D15 with B15 active.
2. Enter the formula in the formula bar.
3. Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter to array enter the formula into all three cells at same time.

---

[image]